# Andengine - text object dosn't visible in updateHandler

Tags: text, andengine, visible

I created a game on andengine. splash screen remove when load resources finish. I want to displays "loading.." I create a text object and attach to splash. It's invisible. But it can't be visible..

here is my onCreateScene method:

```
    protected Scene onCreateScene() {
    this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

    sceneSplash = new Scene();

    splash = new Sprite(0, 0, texRegSplash,
            this.mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());

    tLoading = new Text(0, 0, font, "Loading..",
            mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    tLoading.setPosition((576 - tLoading.getWidth()) / 2,
            1024 - tLoading.getHeight());
    tLoading.setVisible(false);
    splash.attachChild(tLoading);

    this.sceneSplash.attachChild(splash);

    sceneSplash.registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(1f, true,
            new ITimerCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                    tLoading.setVisible(true);
                    sceneSplash.unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
```

//load resources..

```
                    splash.detachSelf();
                    mEngine.setScene(menuHome.getScene());
                }
            }));

    return sceneSplash;

}
```

and here is the problem:

```
tLoading.setVisible(true);
```

not working.. i dont understand why? Thank you for answer..

Comment: what is the size of your sprite? maybe the position of the text is outside of your sprite. a child can just be displayed in the area of his parent

Comment: No.. I am careful. Let's say; if I change "tLoading.setVisibility(true)" before updateHandler, then it seems. But inside onTimePassed "tLoading.setVisibility(true)" not working..

Comment: did you tried to make it static?

Comment: yes.. I tried. But it's not working.. However, I give up and change code..(limited time) Thanks for your help :)